# Keys and mouse randomly stop working briefly

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, performance

Since a couple of days, I experience the weird issue that OS X 10.10.3 does not react to keyboard or mouse inputs, except multitouch gestures like 4-finger swipes. The unresponsiveness will persist for ~20 seconds (I haven't counted yet) and then all clicks and key presses I made during that time seem to be executed quickly one after the other, as if they had been buffered somewhere and the buffer had then been flushed.

I have associated this problem with the following log message in Console

```
IOHIDSystem: postEvent LLEventQueue overflow.
```

Which makes sense as it fits the symptoms. However, I cannot figure out, what exactly triggers this behaviour.

I have an MBP 9,2 with 8GB RAM, a 120GB Samsung EVO SSD as the primary drive and the stock 500GB drive in the optical bay. Both have >30GB free space. Also according to Activity Monitor, the freezes do not coincide with high memory pressure.

I have never had the problem before the recent 10.10.3 update, but I cannot tell if it really relates (since updating, I also have occasional graphics problems, so it may be the update was buggy, it's impossible to tell).

The question is, how can I diagnose the problem exactly or how can I fix it?

*EDIT*: The preceding log messages seem unremarkable, like this

```
26/04/15 21:12:34,057   lsregister[5417]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:12:34,057   lsregister[5417]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:12:52,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80435524b0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80435524b0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:14:39,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80400b0b40) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80400b0b40, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:14:49,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff804166c000) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff804166c000, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:15:13,054   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.quicklook[5428]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
26/04/15 21:15:13,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80435522d0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80435522d0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:15:14,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552780) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552780, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:15:24,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552c30) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552c30, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:16:34,898   lsregister[5465]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:16:34,898   lsregister[5465]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:17:26,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552f00) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552f00, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:17:54,455   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.quicklook[5472]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
26/04/15 21:17:57,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552c30) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552c30, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:18:35,668   lsregister[5483]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:18:35,668   lsregister[5483]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:18:55,394   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.quicklook[5485]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
26/04/15 21:22:17,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff804166c000) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff804166c000, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:22:18,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803eff20f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803eff20f0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:22:30,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803d7fa690) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803d7fa690, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:22:31,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff804166c000) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff804166c000, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:22:32,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80400b0b40) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80400b0b40, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:22:36,508   lsregister[5507]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:22:36,509   lsregister[5507]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:22:39,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552f00) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552f00, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:23:15,425   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.quicklook[5561]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
26/04/15 21:25:41,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803eff2690) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803eff2690, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:26:07,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803d7fa690) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803d7fa690, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:26:22,390   QuickLookUIHelper[5257] NSFileSandboxingRequestRelatedItemExtension: an error was received from pboxd instead of a token. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: 1
26/04/15 21:26:22,390   QuickLookUIHelper[5257] +[NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:] could not get a sandbox extension. primaryPresentedItemURL: file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Rasmus/Downloads/Vuze%20Downloads/Dr.%20House.(2005).Dual.A%CC%81udio.By.Luan.Harper/00-1x22%20-%20Lua%20de%20Mel.mp4, presentedItemURL: file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Rasmus/Downloads/Vuze%20Downloads/Dr.%20House.(2005).Dual.A%CC%81udio.By.Luan.Harper/00-1x22%20-%20Lua%20de%20Mel.AAE
26/04/15 21:26:33,838   QuickLookUIHelper[5257] NSFileSandboxingRequestRelatedItemExtension: an error was received from pboxd instead of a token. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: 1
26/04/15 21:26:33,838   QuickLookUIHelper[5257] +[NSFileCoordinator addFilePresenter:] could not get a sandbox extension. primaryPresentedItemURL: file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Rasmus/Downloads/Vuze%20Downloads/Dr.%20House.(2005).Dual.A%CC%81udio.By.Luan.Harper/00-1x12%20-%20Medicina%20Esportiva.mp4, presentedItemURL: file:///Volumes/Macintosh%20HD/Users/Rasmus/Downloads/Vuze%20Downloads/Dr.%20House.(2005).Dual.A%CC%81udio.By.Luan.Harper/00-1x12%20-%20Medicina%20Esportiva.AAE
26/04/15 21:26:37,370   lsregister[5579]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:26:37,370   lsregister[5579]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:26:47,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803eff20f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803eff20f0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:26:52,287   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.quicklook[5582]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
26/04/15 21:28:38,184   lsregister[5594]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:28:38,184   lsregister[5594]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:28:54,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff80509cc870) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff80509cc870, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:31:49,000   kernel[0]   IOHIDSystem: postEvent LLEventQueue overflow.
 26/04/15 21:32:38,883  lsregister[5610]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:32:38,884   lsregister[5610]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
26/04/15 21:32:51,783   Console[2976]   assertion failed: 14D136: libxpc.dylib + 62495 [D35D0DB2-D7BD-3BE4-8378-062BFE545E1D]: 0x89
26/04/15 21:32:53,840   com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]    (com.apple.quicklook[5615]) Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.quicklook
26/04/15 21:32:54,358   QuickLookSatellite[5616]    CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
26/04/15 21:32:54,358   QuickLookSatellite[5616]    Invalid Connection ID 0
26/04/15 21:32:54,427   QuickLookSatellite[5616]    CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
26/04/15 21:32:54,427   QuickLookSatellite[5616]    CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
26/04/15 21:32:54,447   sandboxd[1046]  ([5616]) QuickLookSatelli(5616) deny file-read-data /Users/Rasmus/Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.revocation.plist
26/04/15 21:32:58,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552c30) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552c30, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:32:58,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803eff20f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803eff20f0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:32:59,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803eff24b0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803eff24b0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:32:59,350   QuickLookSatellite[5616]    In -[NSApplication(NSQuietSafeQuit) _updateCanQuitQuietlyAndSafely], _LSSetApplicationInformationItem(NSCanQuitQuietlyAndSafely) returned error -50
26/04/15 21:33:04,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff803eff20f0) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff803eff20f0, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:33:04,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff804166ce10) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff804166ce10, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:33:05,000   kernel[0]   Google Chrome He (map: 0xffffff8043552f00) triggered DYLD shared region unnest for map: 0xffffff8043552f00, region 0x7fff90a00000->0x7fff90c00000. While not abnormal for debuggers, this increases system memory footprint until the target exits.
26/04/15 21:34:55,262   lsregister[5632]    LaunchServices: Begin database seeding
26/04/15 21:34:55,262   lsregister[5632]    LaunchServices: Completed database seeding
```

Comment: Perhaps include more log information before and after the `IOHIDSystem: postEvent LLEventQueue overflow` event; that's really the only way better understand what might be happening.

Comment: I will paste it, but I had a look myself and the surrounding messages do not seem remarkable, at least I see them at other times too.

Comment: Is it only in one application or does the problem present system-wide?

Comment: Have you tried booting to safe boot and continuing? Try looking at console there and if the problem persists, tell me

Comment: @Allan I have not yet isolated it because it happens so randomly, but I rather think it's independent of the applications running. It often happens when I'm in Chrome, but that might be because I spend most of my time there.

Comment: @oarfish  Just for grins and giggles, can you try using a different browser (Firefox or Safari, but not Opera) for a little while and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @Allan Well, we can rule out the browser. Been using FF a while and left Chrome off during that time, and it just happened again.

Comment: @oarfish Ok..making some progress...A couple more things to try:  Can you reboot in safe mode (hold shift while booting)  This will clear the dyld cache.  Second, can you see if it happens in a native application like TextEdit or Word.  Also, I am curious about that quicklook application.  I am concerned that this application may be causing some issues.  Can you disable/uninstall to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: I'll try with safe mode some time; as for Quicklook, you can't disable it, it's part of OSX.

Comment: Are you mouse and keyboard connected by bluetooth? I found the same issue and this was cause by interference.

Comment: No, they are built-in and I usually have no other devices connected when the error occurs.

Comment: Tried with safe mode, it still happens.

Comment: I've same issue, have you found the solution?

Comment: @SandroDzneladze No, it still happens multiple times a day, but I'm not blocked for 30 seconds or so. Whenever I notice it, I show the desktop via 4-finger-spread and drag the mouse around until I see the selection rectangle which tells me it's working again. I'm not sure if constant dragging somehow speeds it up, but at least I see immediately when it's gone. I will try to reinstall my OS, but can't do it right now.

Comment: @oarfish I've macbook pro retina 2014. basically new. It happens for just few secs. The only peripheral I use is bluetooth mouse. For me its just 5 secs each time, but freakin annoying.

Comment: @SandroDzneladze I have reinstalled OSX (not a clean install, but simply booting to recovery and choosing reinstall, which does not remove any user data), and it still happens. I will try a clean install soon.

Comment: @oarfish I tried not clean reinstall too, and it still happens. but before doing anything else lets wait for el capitano, maybe it fixes something...

Comment: Made another admin user and used that for some time. It took a longer time than usual I think, but it did happen again.

Comment: I erased my hard drive, reinstalled osx and used migration assistant to reinstate everything. It just happened again. I guess the ultimate test would be to erase everything, make a new user and use that for some time to observe. If the bug shows up again, it must be hardware-related.
It seems I'll have to live with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to have disappeared in El Capitan.